# Two file output in Logstash [ELK]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have explored several forums but can't find any answers to my question.
I'm trying to get 2 Filebeat inputs and redirect them via Logstash with 2 different file outputs.

Here are my configuration files:

filebeat.yml:

```yaml
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

# filestream is an input for collecting log messages from files.
- type: filestream

  # Unique ID among all inputs, an ID is required.
  id: ID1
  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  tags: ["tag1"]
  paths:
    - /var/log/site1/access.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*
- type: filestream

  id: ID2
  enabled: true 
  tags: ["tag2"]
  paths:
    - /var/log/site2/access.log
```

Logstash.config:

```rb
input {
     beats {
        port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }

    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }

    mutate {
        convert => {
            "response" => "integer"
            "bytes" => "integer"
  }
 }
}

output {
    if "tag1" in [tags]{
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }

        file {
        path => "/var/central-log/Output1.log"
      }

    }
    else if "tag2" in [tags]{ 
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }

        file {
          path => "/var/central-log/Output2.log"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right method? Can you help me?

Thank you,

Comment: isn't it working ? what if it is neither `tag1` or `tag2` ?

Comment: I tried using the "tag", "type" and "id" fields; and nothing works.

Comment: what does `nothing works` mean ? do you have an error ? nothing happend ? what are the logs from filebeat and logstash saying any errors ?

Comment: I don't have errors, the log files are not created on the Logstash side,
With only one input it works so I guess the problem is in the configuration

Sorry, i'm really new with Logstash

Comment: 0. Add an `else` clause to your output in logstash
1. Are you sure you are able to read from those 2 files ?
2. Are sure you manage to send data to logstash ?
I am positive it is possible to have multiple output like you have

Comment: I just added an else at the end, when there is only one output, it has the right to create a file in the same place so I guess it has the right.
When I do the config and output test, I don't have errors

Comment: sorry the `are you sure you are bale to read data from those 2 files` was meant at filebeat. Are you sure filebeat is sending the data to logstash succesfully

Comment: Yes, independently both filebeat send data to logstash, it is once both at the same time that nothing happens